# Interpreting an exponential distribution for mathematical model.

Tags: probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, exponential-distribution

I am making a model on how robots choose between two shelter sites once they are evicted from their home. I will provide a brief description on the model.

Based on the model, there are three distinct phases on choosing the shelter where the robots finally settle in;

Phase ‘Search’ = Robots will search for potential shelter sites to move in this phase.

Phase ‘Assessment’ = Robots will assess if the potential shelter sites they  found is good or not.

Phase ‘Recruitment’ = Robots will take/convince other robot nest mates to come along with them to the newly found nest.

These are the three distinct stages in the decision making process. According to the model we assume that the robot have to choose a shelter, once the time since she is evicted from nest is greater than the threshold time to pick a shelter. The threshold time to pick a shelter is dependent on the quality of the shelter .Essentially a robot will take another robot to the shelter if the time passed since she is removed from her home is greater than a threshold time to pick a home. So if she finds a good shelter first, she will initiate recruitment to the good shelter faster.

Question:
From data, i calculated the Search duration, Assessment duration and Recruitment duration. From that i found that Search duration, Assessment duration and Recruitment duration to good shelter following  an exponential distribution. Can anyone suggest me the implication of these distributions to the model? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, you have not asked a mathematical question so this will probably be closed. I suspect the reason you have found exponential distributions is that you built that into the program that runs the simulation. I don't know what you mean when you ask for the implication/ These distributions will behave like exponential distributions. Since you know what those are you can draw conclusions.

Comment: @EthanBolker Apologies. From the data, i calculated the durations and it follows an exponential distribution. What i was asking is, whether these exponetial distribution can give me an idea whether to accept or reject the model?

Comment: Whether or not to accept a model depends on your sense/intuition about the phenomenon you are modeling. Do the results suggest reasonable or appropriate robot behavior? Should the intervals peak and then tail off as exponential models do?

Comment: I havenot simulated the model yet, i just calculated some parameters from the data as mentioned above. From these parameters will i be able to make predictions on whether to accept or reject the model?

Comment: I don't know, nor can anyone but you. Run the simulations and decide if you like what you see..